# Probability approximation and computation given Compound Poisson random variable

Tags: random-variable, poisson-distribution

Consider a compound Poisson random variable $S = \Sigma_{i=1}^N X_i $ where N is Poisson with mean 2 and $X_i$ is equally likely to be  any of 1,2,3,4 . Find P{S = 6}.

***Solution:***

Let me solve this problem. We are given that $S = \Sigma_{i=1}^N X_i $ where N is Poisson with mean 2 and $X_i$ is equally likely to be any of 1,2,3,4. We need to find the probability that S = 6.

Since N is Poisson with mean 2, the probability mass function of N is given by $P(N=k) = \displaystyle\frac{e^{-2}2^k}{k!}$ for $k = 0,1,2,\dots$

The conditional distribution of S given N=k is the distribution of the sum of k independent and identically distributed random variables, each of which is equally likely to be any of 1,2,3,4. Therefore, the conditional distribution of S given N=k is the k-fold convolution of the uniform distribution on {1,2,3,4}.

Let's denote by $p_k$ the probability that S=6 given that N=k. Then we have:

$p_0 = P(S=6|N=0) = 0$ since if there are no terms in the sum, the sum must be zero.

$p_1 = P(S=6|N=1) = 0$ since if there is only one term in the sum, it must be one of 1,2,3,4.

$p_2 = P(S=6|N=2) = \displaystyle\frac{3}{16}$ since there are two terms in the sum and each term can be any of 1,2,3,4. Three ways for the sum to be 6 are (4,2)(2,4),(3,3)

$p_3 = P(S=6|N=3) = \displaystyle\frac{10}{64}$ since there are three terms in the sum and each term can be any of 1,2,3,4. The 10 ways for the sum to be 6 are (1,1,4)(1,4,1),(4,1,1),(1,2,3),(3,2,1),(1,3,2),(3,1,2),(2,3,1),(2,1,3),(2,2,2).

$p_4 = P(S=6|N=4) = \displaystyle\frac{10}{256}$ since there are four terms in the sum and each term can be any of 1,2,3,4. The  ten ways for the sum to be 6 are (1,1,1,3)(1,1,3,1)(1,3,1,1),(3,1,1,1),(2,2,1,1),(2,1,2,1),(2,1,1,2),(1,1,2,2),(1,2,1,2),(1,2,2,1).

There are five ways for the sum to be 6 when there are five terms in the sum and each term can be any of 1,2,3,4. Those are (1,1,1,1,2),(1,1,1,2,1),(1,1,2,1,1),(1,2,1,1,1),(2,1,1,1,1). So the correct value for $p_5$ should be $p_5 = P(S=6|N=5) = \displaystyle\frac{5}{1024}$.

Similarly, there is also one way for the sum to be 6 when there are six terms in the sum and each term can be any of 1,2,3,4. That is if all six terms are 1. So the correct value for $p_6$ should be $p_6 = P(S=6|N=6) = \displaystyle\frac{1}{4096}$.

the probability that S equals 6 becomes:

$P(S=6) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} P(S=6|N=k)P(N=k)$

$P(S=6) = P(N=0)\cdot p_0 + P(N=1)\cdot p_1 + P(N=2)\cdot p_2 + P(N=3)\cdot p_3 + P(N=4)\cdot p_4 + P(N=5)\cdot p_5 + P(N=6)\cdot p_6$

$$ P(S=6) = \displaystyle\frac{e^{-2}2^0}{0!} \times 0 + \displaystyle\frac{e^{-2}2^1}{1!} \times 0 + \displaystyle\frac{e^{-2}2^2}{2!} \times \displaystyle\frac{3}{16} + \displaystyle\frac{e^{-2}2^3}{3!} \times \displaystyle\frac{10}{64} + \displaystyle\frac{e^{-2}2^4}{4!} \times \displaystyle\frac{10}{256} + \displaystyle\frac{e^{-2}2^5}{5!}\times \displaystyle\frac{5}{1024} +
 \displaystyle\frac{e^{-2}2^6}{6!} \times \displaystyle\frac{1}{4096}$$

$P(S=6) = \displaystyle\frac{e^{-2}\cdot 3}{8} + \displaystyle\frac{e^{-2}\cdot 10}{48} + \displaystyle\frac{e^{-2}\cdot 10}{384} + \displaystyle\frac{e^{-2}}{768} + \displaystyle\frac{e^{-2}}{46080}$

$P(S=6) ≈ 0.0826$

So the probability that S equals 6 is approximately **0.0826**.

Comment: For each value of $N$ (from 2 to 6) you might want to list out the possible outcomes.  For example with $N=2$ the possible outcomes are (3,3), (2,4), and (4,2).

Comment: In `R` you can check your result with a simulation such as `S <- sapply(rpois(1e4, 2), \(n) sum(sample.int(4, n, replace = TRUE))); sum(S==6)/length(S)` By inspecting `S` (as in `table(S)`) you might get some insight into how to compute the probabilities correctly.  Notice, too, that 3+3=6.

Comment: @whuber, When I implemented your 'R' program in 'R', 'R' gave me answer 0.0855. How is that?

Comment: Because your answer is incorrect ;-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach looks correct but it's incomplete.

Here is a schematic of all the ways you can form $6$ from a sum of values of $X_i,$ organized by their unordered values:

```
N | Total ways | X's
- | ---------- | ----
1 |          0 | [Omitted: 6]
2 |          3 | 24, 42;  33; [Omitted: 51, 15]
3 |         10 | 114, 141, 411;  222;  123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321
4 |         10 | 1113, 1131, 1311, 3111;  1122, 1212, 2112, 2211, 2121, 1221
5 |          5 | 11112, 11121, 11211, 12111, 21111
6 |          1 | 111111
```

Thus, when $N=2$ the chance of forming $S=6$ is $3/4^2;$ when $N=3$ the chance of $S=6$ is $10/4^3;$ and so on.  To obtain the answer (which a quick simulation suggests must be close to $0.082$), apply the rules of conditional expectation:

$$\Pr(S=6) = \Pr(S=6\mid N=2)\Pr(N=2) + \cdots + \Pr(S=6\mid N=6)\Pr(N=6).$$

---

The pattern of total ways $0,3,10,10,5,1$ (beginning with $N=1$) derives from the sequence $1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1$ of binomial coefficients counting the [compositions of 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)).  The first two values are reduced from $1$ to $0$ and $5$ to $3$ because the compositions $6=6$ and $6=1+5=5+1$ are not available since no $X_i$ can exceed $4.$

Comment: You answered this question using permutation. Combination is used in my answer. That means in your answer, order of values matters whereas in my answer, order of values doesn't matter. 

Comment: The question is worded to imply the order *does* matter.  You can discover this by considering the simple subproblem where, say $N=2.$ What is $\Pr(S=6)$ in this case? This is tantamount to asking the chance that the sum on two four-sided dice is $6.$  There are many ways to work it out, but *they all are equivalent* and there's only one correct answer.